# C++ How do I make my code stop after the user enters three wrong guesses

Tags: c++

[the point of my code is to make the user input their guess. if their guess is 4 the code breaks if is not then they have 2 more chances out of the three.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOA2G.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Have you written anything at all?  I'm looking at your question, not clicking links. For specific feedback, please show how much effort you put into it, and where you are stuck.  Start with a counter, that you decrement with each failed guess, and if it reaches 0, break out of your loop.

Comment: //  Variables in C++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int number;
int correct=4;
int guess=0;
do
{
  cout << "Enter a number: ";    
  cin >> number;
  guess=(guess+1);
} while (number!=correct);
while (guess==3) break;
}

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text, please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: my code doesnt stop afte 3 wrong guesses only when i guess the correct number

Comment: also it says it needs formatting and I tried but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "merge" two `while` loops by using [logical operators](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/#logical):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number;
    int correct = 4;
    int guess = 0;
    
    do {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> number;
        guess = guess + 1;
        
    } while (guess < 3 && number != correct);
    
    return 0;
}
```